# Returning mix result from same object in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am working with WebAPI where I have come to the situation where I want to return an object with different result from a single method.
EG. Let's take an example of student

**Object/Class:**

```
public class student
{
    //Some properties
}

public class error
{
    //Some properties
}

public class ResponseObject
{
    //Some properties
    public student stud {get; set;}
    public error err {get; set;}
}
```

**Method:**

```
public ResponseObject StudentsDetail(string a, string b)
{
    //Some code
}
```

Now here, I want to send students details if the call is successfull
otherwise error message.

Whenever I am sending the response the ResponseObject object contains all the properties of the both the classes student and error.

I want to send one of them.
How can I achieve this?
Is it possible with dependancy injection?
Or suggest me the other way.

For more clarification I am updating my question here.
Response sample will be like this

Success Json Response

```
{
    "title": "Student",
    "message": "success",
    "student": {
        "id": {
            "name": "abc",
            "add": "xyz"
        }
    }
}
```

Error Json Response

```
{
    "title": "Student",
    "message": "error",
    "error": {
        "message": {
            "text": "asdlkj"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what about change it to void method then pass both Student and Error as  the 3rd and 4th parameters?

Comment: Then how can I send response back to my request?

Answer (score 0):

```
Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, student)
```

OR

```
Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, error)
```

according to your needs

Comment: ResponseObject has other properties too, that needs to be there everytime I send the response. wheather with student object or error object. So with your solution I can't achieve this.

Comment: Dear sir, Here the question is how can I send my ResponseObject with one of the object property. Not the question of how to send the response back?